# update table when subquery matches

Tags: mysql

I am trying this query but it outputs a syntax error in the subquery.

What is the problem and how can be solved? thanks

```
  UPDATE CompradorCategorias_new as A
    SET A.idParent=(
        SELECT idcategoria 
        FROM categoriasi18n_new
        WHERE 
        (
            SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(NomeComPath, '>', 2) 
            FROM CompradorCategorias_new
            = 
            SELECT translationWithPath 
            FROM categoriasi18n_new
        )
    )
```

Comment: What is the specific syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good in your query *until* the `WHERE` clause - at that point, it's all kinds of wrong. You can actually drop that block and use a regular `WHERE` clause comparison (instead of a second sub-query):

```
UPDATE
    CompradorCategorias_new AS A
SET
    A.idParent = (
        SELECT
            idcategoria
        FROM
            categoriasi18n_new AS B
        WHERE
            B.translationWithPath = SUBSTRING_INDEX(A.NomeComPath, '>', 2)
    )
```